# apoc.spatial.geocode() throws RuntimeException

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm facing this error:

`Failed to invoke procedure "apoc.spatial.geocode": Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read url http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?format=json&q=Duomo+Milano as json: Connection refused: connect`

when I run

`CALL apoc.spatial.geocode("Duomo Milano",1) YIELD location, latitude, longitude, description RETURN location, latitude, longitude, description`

Could it be something related to APOC plugin configuration?
I also found that rows into debug.log file:

`` 2017-04-28 08:39:10.592+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.couchbase.CouchbaseConnection` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: com/couchbase/client/java/document/Document 2017-04-28 08:39:10.593+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.couchbase.CouchbaseManager` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: com/couchbase/client/java/env/CouchbaseEnvironment 2017-04-28 08:39:10.593+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.couchbase.document.CouchbaseUtils` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: com/couchbase/client/core/message/kv/MutationToken 2017-04-28 08:39:10.751+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.mongodb.MongoDBColl` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: org/bson/conversions/Bson 2017-04-28 08:39:10.914+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.GsonJsonProvider` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: com/google/gson/JsonElement 2017-04-28 08:39:10.915+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode 2017-04-28 08:39:10.917+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JacksonJsonProvider` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper 2017-04-28 08:39:10.918+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonOrgJsonProvider` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: org/json/JSONException 2017-04-28 08:39:10.921+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.GsonMappingProvider$1` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: com/google/gson/Gson 2017-04-28 08:39:10.921+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.GsonMappingProvider$2` from plugin jar `/C:/Users/gi.silvestri/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.1.3.6-all.jar`: com/google/gson/Gson ``

I'm running neo4j 3.1.1 Community Edition server on Windows x64 machine (but I got the same on Ubuntu 12.0.4 environment, with same Neo4j version).

Comment: try apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce insted of apoc.spatial.geocode, also try to change your geocoding API to google or others... check docs for instructions https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_spatial_2

Comment: @Tomaž Bratanič thanks for your suggestion. I solved: it's just because I'm using a proxy over the net where I run Neo4j server, so all external calls are denied.